# sqlite-net-pcl queries are returning correct row count but all data is null or 0

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite-net-pcl

Help Please.
I am trying to learn xamarin c-sharp. To that end I have learned just enough of the basics that I felt confident trying to make a simple SQLite Db app.

I am using sqlite-net-pcl. I have tried Xamarin.Android as well as Xamarin.Forms. I have run the app on two different win10 computers. I have run the app on an emulator as well as on my phone. All with the same results . . . all returned data is 0 or null.

I have an existing **non-empty** db (textdb.db
):

I have searched the web and found a few people complaining of the same results but I can not find a solution.

I hope that someone out there will see something and tell me what is wrong.

Structure:
table: testtable
...................
id, INT, primary key
data, BIGINT

Data
id = 1
data = 2
...................

My Code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Google.Android.Material.FloatingActionButton;
using Google.Android.Material.Snackbar;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using SQLite;
using System.Linq;

namespace android_db_app
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        . . .
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
        . . .
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
        . . .
        }

        private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
        . . .
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
        . . .
       }

        public void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object o,o1;
            string dbname = "test.db";
            string s = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, @"DailyReminder/DB/" + dbname);
            if (!File.Exists(s))
                s = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, dbname);
            SQLiteAsyncConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(s);//SQLiteConnection.Table
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM testtable;";
            string sql1 = "SELECT ID FROM testtable;";
            o = dbConnection.Table<testtable>();
            o1 =  dbConnection.QueryAsync<int>(sql1,0);
        }
    }

    public class testtable
    {
        public Int32 id;
        public Int64 data;
    }
}
```

All results in the objects are value 0 instead of 1 and 2.

Comment: first, you are making async db calls without using await.  Second, you should really use the ORM capabilities of the library instead of trying to write raw SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

For my sqlite.net, this is my setting:

0 I'm creating a class in Models folder

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
   public class testtable
     {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public int data {get; set; }
     }
}
```

1 Inside MainActivity.cs (Android)

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        string dbName = "your_table_name.db3";
        string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, dbName);
        LoadApplication(new App(dbPath));
    }
```

2 Inside App.xaml.cs:

```
    public static string DatabasePath = string.Empty; //sqlite

    public App(string databasePath)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new View.MainPage());

        DatabasePath = databasePath; //sqlite
    }
```

3 Calling the database, for example you want to call the database when a page appear:

```
    using MyApp.Models;
    ...
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
         using SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabasePath);
         conn.CreateTable<testtable>();
         List<testtable> notes = conn.Table<testtable>().ToList();
    }
```

Comment: you can read more about sqlite-net-pcl from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases
or here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately conn.CreateTable<testtable>(); throws error System.Exception: 'Cannot create a table without columns (does 'android_db_app.testtable' have public properties?)' I think I will try downloading the example provided in the link you provided.

Comment: as the error states, the DB columns must be public properties.  Yours are public fields, not properties

Comment: Jason's answer is the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i'm forget about the declaration, i'll add my models declaration

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a class with your ID, like this

```
class IdResult
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
o1 =  dbConnection.QueryAsync<IdResult>(sql1,0);
```

You will see your ID in IdResult.ID.